# How to create a cart logic with React/Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create a cart page logic with Redux, but since I'm still a bit new to it, I can't figure out how to implement the logic. I didn't have a problem making the same logic in my previous project where every component was rendered in App component, but now I have a multipage app (cart page as well) so I'm trying to adapt the code I'm already familiar with, to this project. How can I achieve that?

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App.jsx';
import VinylClocks from './Components/VinylClocks.jsx';
import CustomClocks from './Components/CustomClocks.jsx';
import About from './Components/About.jsx';
import Contact from './Components/Contact.jsx';
import Cart from './Components/Cart.jsx';
import ProductPage from './Components/ProductPage.jsx';
import './index.css';
import {
  createBrowserRouter,
  RouterProvider,
  Route,
} from "react-router-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux"; //Provider
import store from "./store/store.js";

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <App/>,
  },
  {
    path: "vinylclocks",
    element: <VinylClocks/>,
  },
  {
    path: "customclocks",
    element: <CustomClocks/>,
  },
  {
    path: "about",
    element: <About/>,
  },
  {
    path: "contact",
    element: <Contact/>,
  },
  {
    path: "cart",
    element: <Cart/>,
  },
  {
    path: "product/productpage/:name",
    element: <ProductPage/>,
  },
]);

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
    <Provider store={store}> 
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
)
```

```
import React from "react";
import "./ProductPage.css";
import Navbar from "./Navbar.jsx";
import Footer from "./Footer.jsx";
import { data } from "./data.js";
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { addItem } from '../features/cart/cartSlice.js';
 

export default function ProductPage() {
  
    const { name } = useParams();

    const item = data.find(item => item.name === name);

    const onClickHandler = (inventoryItem) => {
      dispatch(addItem(inventoryItem));
    };

  if (!item) {
    return <div>No item</div>;
  }
    return (
      <>
        <Navbar/>
        <div className="productPage-container" key={item.id}>
            <div className="image-container">
                <img src={item.img}/>
            </div>
            <div className="about-product">
                <h2 className="product-name">{item.name}</h2>
                <span className="product-type">{item.type}</span>
                <span className="product-price">${item.price}</span>
                <p className="product-desc">{item.desc}</p>
                <button onClick={() => onClickHandler(inventoryItem)} className="addToCart"> Add to Cart</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <Footer/>
      </>  
      );
}
```

```
import React from 'react';
import {changeItemQuantity} from '../features/cart/cartSlice.js';

export default function Cart(props) {

  const { cart, dispatch } = props;
  
  const onInputChangeHandler = (name, input) => {
    // If the user enters a bad value...
    if (input === '') {
      return;
    }

    // Otherwise, convert the input into a number and pass it along as the newQuantity.
    const newQuantity = Number(input);

    dispatch(changeItemQuantity(name, newQuantity));

  };

  // Use the cart and currencyFilter slices to render their data.
  const cartElements = Object.keys(cart).map(createCartItem);
  const total = calculateTotal(cart);

  return (
    <div id="cart-container">
      <ul id="cart-items">{cartElements}</ul>
      <h3 className="total">
        Total{' '}
        <span className="total-value">
          {total} 
        </span>
      </h3>
    </div>
  );

  function createCartItem(name) {
    const item = cart[name];

    if (item.quantity === 0) {
      return;
    }

    return (
      <li key={name}>
        <p>{name}</p>
        <select
          className="item-quantity"
          value={item.quantity}
          onChange={(e) => {
            onInputChangeHandler(name, e.target.value);
          }}
        >
          {[...Array(100).keys()].map((_, index) => (
            <option key={index} value={index}>
              {index}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
      </li>
    );
  }
};
```

ProductPage renders the product which was previously clicked on, along with its details, and there the user should be able to add product to the cart.
The Error I get on Cart page: Unexpected Application Error!
Cannot convert undefined or null to object
TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
at Function.keys ()
at Cart

Comment: The `Cart` component isn't passed any props, so `cart` and `dispatch` are undefined. `Object.keys(cart)`, or rather `Object.keys(undefined)`, causes that error. What is `cart` supposed to be in the `Cart` component? Please [edit] to clarify and to provide a more complete [mcve] if necessary.

Comment: That is the part I have a problem with most. Cart isn't passed cart={state.cart} and  dispatch={dispatch} because it doesn't have a parent component (intentionally so) since I need it to be a separate page. And I'm not sure how to pass those to a component which doesn't have a parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The `Cart` component isn't passed any props, so `props.cart` and `cart.dispatch` are both undefined in that component. Use the `useDispatch` and `useSelector` hooks from `react-redux` to subscribe to state changes and access the `dispatch` function.
2. The `RouterProvider` rendering `Cart` and all the other routed components is rendered into a separate ReactTree than the Redux `Provider` component providing the store.

index.js - Fix the code so that the Redux `Provider` wraps and provides the store to the `RouterProvider` and UI components.

```
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}> 
      <RouterProvider router={router} />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
);
```

ProductPage

```
import React from "react";
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import "./ProductPage.css";
import Navbar from "./Navbar.jsx";
import Footer from "./Footer.jsx";
import { data } from "./data.js";
import { addItem } from '../features/cart/cartSlice.js';
 
export default function ProductPage() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { name } = useParams();

  const item = data.find(item => item.name === name);

  const onClickHandler = (inventoryItem) => {
    dispatch(addItem(inventoryItem));
  };

  if (!item) {
    return <div>No item</div>;
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Navbar />
      <div className="productPage-container" key={item.id}>
        <div className="image-container">
          <img src={item.img} />
        </div>
        <div className="about-product">
          <h2 className="product-name">{item.name}</h2>
          <span className="product-type">{item.type}</span>
          <span className="product-price">${item.price}</span>
          <p className="product-desc">{item.desc}</p>
          <button
            onClick={() => onClickHandler(inventoryItem)}
            className="addToCart"
          >
            Add to Cart
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <Footer/>
    </>  
  );
}
```

Cart

```
import React from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { changeItemQuantity } from '../features/cart/cartSlice.js';

export default function Cart() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const cart = useSelector(state => state.cart); // * Note
  
  ...

  // Use the cart and currencyFilter slices to render their data.
  const cartElements =Object.entries(cart).map(createCartItem);
  const total = calculateTotal(cart);

  return (
    <div id="cart-container">
      <ul id="cart-items">
        {cartElements}
      </ul>
      <h3 className="total">
        Total{' '}
        <span className="total-value">
          {total} 
        </span>
      </h3>
    </div>
  );

  function createCartItem([name, item]) {
    if (item.quantity === 0) {
      return;
    }

    return (
      <li key={name}>
        <p>{name}</p>
        <select
          className="item-quantity"
          value={item.quantity}
          onChange={(e) => {
            onInputChangeHandler(name, e.target.value);
          }}
        >
          {[...Array(100).keys()].map((_, index) => (
            <option key={index} value={index}>
              {index}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
      </li>
    );
  }
};
```

***Note:** Ensure that whatever you are selecting from state is a valid object that can be passed to `Object.entries`.*

Comment: Huge thanks for trying to help me with this, and it seems it might work, but for some reason I can't import Provider from 'react-redux'. It says - Failed to resolve import "react-redux" from "src\main.jsx".

Comment: @Igor The `Provider` component is a named export, use `import { Provider } from 'react-redux';`. If the issue is the `react-redux` module then please check and ensure all project dependencies are correctly installed. Check that you are using current/compatible versions.

Comment: @Igor Check what is ***installed***, e.g. run `npm list react-redux` to see what is actually installed in the project directory. You could also just re-run `npm install` to install what is specified in your package.json file. Check that those versions are all correct.

Comment: All the dependencies are there. "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^2.0.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.20.0", I read somewhere that react needs to be 16.0.0 or greater, which it is.

Comment: @Igor Yeah, you should definitely be on React@16 or later by now, you are on React 18 so that's all good. I don't see `react-redux` listed there.

Comment: For  npm list react-redux, it says:
craft-vinyl-art@0.0.0 C:\Users\igorz\craft-vinyl-art
└── (empty)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256470/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-igor).

Comment: Oh. I only installed the toolkit for some reason. I installed it now. Thanks for that!